# Unit Testing Event Listeners

Tags: java, unit-testing, event-listener

I need to unit test the functionality of an event listener but I've never done it before and I can't seem to find an example anywhere about it. Does anyone have any suggestions on a good way to go about this?

Comment: What kind of event listeners?

Comment: It is it's own class (not anonymous) and it implements an interface that isn't part of the standard java libraries (that interface extends EventListener directly).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's not much to it, construct the event listener, pass in a mock event, and test.

```
@Test
public void testEventListener() {
  ActionListener subjectUnderTest = new MyActionListener();
  ActionEvent mockEvent = mock(ActionEvent.class);
  // Or just create a new ActionEvent, e.g. new ActionEvent();
  // setup mock

  subjectUnderTest.actionPerformed(mockEvent);

  // validate
}
```

Problems can arise when you follow the standard patterns for creating event listeners, where you define an anonymous class that directly interacts with the containing class.  However it shouldn't be hard to refactor such a class into its own full class, and pass in any dependencies to the constructor, rather than implicitly from the surrounding class.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but how do I go about setting up the mock event? Is there something simple I can use within the standard java libraries to do this or does it require external libraries?

Comment: Generally, you use a mocking library to do this, however if you didn't want to use one you could just create an instance of an event directly.  I'm a fan of the [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) library, very easy to use.  If you haven't run into creating mock objects in unit testing before, you're severely limiting the types of tests you can run.  I'd recommend [Practical Unit Testing with TestNG and Mockito](http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Unit-Testing-TestNG-Mockito/dp/839348930X) as a primer.

Comment: I have only done relatively simple unit tests and haven't needed to mock objects, but I have heard of it. I appreciate the guidance and I'll make sure to take a look at that primer. Thanks for the help.