# How to unit test event firing?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Suppose I have an object, that should fire some event on some operation?

How would I test it?

I can add listener to it, but the code of listener will be separated from testing.

```
final ArrayList<MyEvent> eventsFired = new ArrayList<>();
myObject.addMyEventListener(new MyEventListener() {
   public void myEventHappened(MyEvent evt) {
      eventsFired.add(evt);
   }
});
result = myObject.runOperation();
assert(result, ...);
assert(eventsFired.size(), ...); // is by one grater than before operation
assert(eventsFired.get(eventdFired.size()-1_, ...) // is correct
```

How to get them in one place?

**UPDATE**

Can I write something like this:

```
assertThat( myObject.runOperation() ).fires( ... )
```

or something like

```
Events events = captureEvents( object.runOperation() );
assertThat( events...)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "separated from testing" and "to get them in one place"?

Comment: This solution suggests using a mock event: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977403/unit-testing-event-listeners)

Comment: @RobP as far as I understood he does not want to test the (a) event listener, but the event producer. Thus the example code looks fine to me if using standard assertions are his way to go.

Comment: @Vampire yes I am testing producer. Is there a shorter way? With some library for example?

Answer (score 0):

Your test looks ok, you basically are building a spy object that will help you performing the assert you need.

If you really feel better using a dedicated test tool, Mockito.spy does this kind of things too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like JMockit with its Expectations to achieve this. I'm not sure how short it will be, but it will be nicer to read and write I think. Didn't do much with JMockit myself yet, so I cannot give an example.